# Python virtual environment breaks shtab

Tags: zsh, python

I recently created a Python virtual environment for all my local CLI scripts. Before that change, the command

```
shtab --shell=zsh rbackup.get_parser | sudo tee /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_rb
```

worked as intended, creating auto-completion for `rb` (which is a symlink to the actual script file `rbackup.py`. Now I installed shtab in my virtual environment, and it outputs the required content for `_rb`, but auto-completion does not work for `rb`. What am I missing here?

Comment: What _exactly_ does "does not work for `rb`" mean? Does the command that you show generate errors?

Comment: The arguments for `rb` are simply not auto-completed (it still works for ssh in the same shell).

Comment: The command quoted above works perfectly well (filling `_rb`).

Answer (score 0):

Updating to macOS 13.3 fixed the problem.